# PySpark RDD transformation

Tags: mapreduce, apache-spark, pyspark

i have a RDD with a list of floats:

> [1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 2.0]

and i want a transformed RDD like this:

> [(1.0, 3.0), (1.0, 4.0), (1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 4.0), (3.0, 2.0), (4.0,
>   2.0)]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`RDD.cartesian`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.cartesian).

> Return the Cartesian product of this RDD and another one, that is, the RDD of all pairs of elements *(a, b)* where *a* is in *self* and *b* is in *other*.

```
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([1, 2])
>>> sorted(rdd.cartesian(rdd).collect())
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Note that this returns the pairs in both directions. Hopefully this is not a problem for you.

Comment: Great, thank you. i have to eliminate pairs (1,1) and stay only with one direction, so this is my next problem :)

Comment: You could number them (`zipWithIndex`) and `filter` the results by the two indices (`i1 < i2`).

Comment: Oh. In your example output you had both `(3.0, 4.0)` and `(3.0, 2.0)`. So I thought simply filtering by the values would not be enough. But it's great if that works. You could even drop the first filter since the second will also exclude the _equals_ case.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, i resolved with `rdd.filter(lambda (x, y): x<y)`, the last comment was a test i did.